# Interactive diagram depends on data in database

Tags: javascript, gojs

I gonna do the diagram in which the nodes will be changing color depends on data from the database. I gonna save and load json model through the database. And the question is: how to make a trigger of changing node color if the data in db updated.

Answer (score 0):

> And the question is: how to make a trigger of changing node color if the data in db updated.

I think you mean: How do you change the model data so that the Diagram reflects the updateS? You must use `Model.setDataProperty` or `Model.set` (alias)

https://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Model.html#setDataProperty

Example:

```js
  var node = myDiagram.findNodeForKey("Alpha");

  // Model.commit executes the given function within a transaction
  myDiagram.model.commit(function(m) {  // this Model

    // This is the safe way to change model data
    // GoJS will be notified that the data has changed
    // and can update the node in the Diagram
    // and record the change in the UndoManager
    m.set(node.data, "color", "red");

  }, "change color");

  // outputs "red" - the model has changed!
  console.log(node.data.color);
```

This is covered in the [GraphObject Manipulation tutorial](https://gojs.net/latest/learn/graphobject.html), under the heading *Changing Properties and Updating the Model using Data Bindings*.